# Calculate the zeros of a polynomial in finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

How to calculate polynomial zeros ${y^3} - \left( {{x^2}} \right)y + x\left( {{y^2}} \right)$ in ${\mathbb{F}_5}\left[ {x,y} \right]$?

Comment: Naive approach: Try the $5^2$ possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

The polynomial is homogeneous of degree $3$. Each non-zero solution lies on a line of solutions.

Thus it is sufficient to consider $y=1$, the partially evaluated polynomial $1+x-x^2$ has the solution $(x,y)=(3,1)$, thus also $(1,2)$, so that $y-2x$ is a linear factor of the given polynomial. Extracting this factor gives the full factorization as
$$
y^3+y^2x-yx^2=y(y^2-2y(2x)+(2x)^2)=y(y-2x)^2\pmod5
$$

Comment: Using homogeneity is, of course, the key. Just adding the remark that the equation $y=0$ also defines a line:-) Or, if you prefer, the point with homoegeneous coordinates $[1:0]$ is on the projective in addition to the points $[x:1]$. Your method did find that solution as well, so no problem there!

Comment: In principle one could leave the motivational intro out and just start with factoring out $y$ and completing the square in the remaining quadratic factor using $1=-4\pmod5$, or $1=6=-9\pmod5$.